# Error in program calculations, converting of types

Tags: c++, function, pointers, math, type-conversion

I have made a program that takes words inputted from the user, turns them into numbers, runs calculations and then turns them back into words, simple enough, however I'm having an error with my code.

Whenever I try to input a hundred or higher value, I am getting the output "zero". (Most likely meaning the number I'm trying to convert is zero, when it shouldn't be.)

For this reason I think the problem is in the calculation function "write_value" however, I'm not sure what.

I'v have been at this for the past couple of hours, so it could be something small I'm not seeing, however it might several things, so instead of wasting more time, I thought I'd post it here for some more experienced people to have a look.

Thanks in advance for any help. ^^

Sample input would be:
one_hundred_forty_four + two_hundred_thirty_eight

Correct Output:
three_hundred_eighty_two

Current Output:
zero

Current Code:

```
using namespace std;

/**
 * Map units digits into words
 * 
 */
string units[] = {
    "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
    "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen",
    "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
};

/**
 * Map tens digits into words
 */
string tens[] = {
    "", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"
};

/**
 * Splits a string into components
 * 
 * @param words array for the components (assumed large enough)
 * @param base the string to split
 * @param separator the separator character
 * @return pointer to the first unused element in the array
 */
string* split(string* words, string base, char separator) {
    string* result = words;
    istringstream input(base);
    string token;
    while (getline(input, token, separator)) {
        if (token.length() > 0 && token != "and") {
            if (token == "hundred") {
                *--result += "_hundred";
                *result++;
            } else if (token == "thousand") {
                *--result += "_thousand";
                *result++;
            } else if (token == "million") {
                *--result += "_million";
                *result++;
            } else {
                *result++ = token;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Joins an array of component strings into a single string
 * 
 * @param words pointer to first component
 * @param end pointer to the component beyond the last
 * @param separator the separator character
 * @return the joined string
 */
string join(string* words, string* end, char separator) {
    string result;
    if (words < end) {
        result.append(*words);
        for (string* w = words + 1; w < end; w++) {
            result.append(separator + *w);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Writes number words into an array
 * 
 * @param words array to store the words
 * @param n the number to write
 * @return pointer to the first unused element
 */
string* write_value(string* words, int n) {
    string* result = words;


    int t = (n % 100) / 10;
    int u = (n % 10);

    if (t == 1) { // fixes teens
        t--;
        u += 10;
    }
    if (t) {
        *result++ = tens[t];
    }
    if (u) {
        *result++ = units[u];
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Reads an array of number words
 * 
 * @param words the number words to read
 * @param end pointer to the word beyond the last
 * @return the value read
 */
int read_value(string* words, string* end) {
    int result = 0;
    string* w = words;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (*w == tens[i]) {
            result += 10 * i;
            w += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        if (*w == units[i]) {
            result += i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Writes a number word string
 * 
 * @param n the number to write
 * @return the word string
 */
string Wordnum::write_number(int n) {
    string result;
    string words[20]; 
    string* end;
    if (n == 0) {
        result = "zero";
    } else if (n < 0) {
        end = write_value(words, -n);
        result = "negative_" + join(words, end, '_');
    } else {

        if (n > 100) {
            end = write_value(words, n);
            result = join(words, end, '_') + "hundred_";
        } else if (n > 1000) {
            end = write_value(words, n);
            result = join(words, end, '_') + "thousand_";
        } else if (n > 1000000) {
            end = write_value(words, n);
            result = join(words, end, '_') + "million_";
        }
        end = write_value(words, n);
        result = join(words, end, '_');
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Reads a number word string
 * 
 * @param n the string to read
 * @return the value read
 */
int Wordnum::read_number(string n) {
    int result;
    string words[20]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
        n[i] = tolower(n[i]);
        if (n[i] == '-') n[i] = '_';
    }
    string* end = split(words, n, '_');

    if (end == words || words[0] == "zero") {
        result = 0;
    } else if (words[0] == "negative") {
        result = -read_value(words + 1, end);
    } else {
        result = read_value(words, end);

        for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
            if (words[i] == "hundred") {
                result = read_value(words - 1, end) * 100;
                break;
            } else if (words[i] == "thousand") {
                result = read_value(words - 1, end) * 1000;
                break;
            } else if (words[i] == "million") {
                result = read_value(words - 1, end) * 1000000;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Inserts a Wordnum into an output stream as a word string
 * 
 * @param os the stream to insert into
 * @param n the value to insert
 * @return the modified stream
 */
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Wordnum& n) {
    return os << Wordnum::write_number(n.value_);
}

/**
 * Extracts a Wordnum in word string form from an input stream
 * 
 * @param is the stream to extract from
 * @param n the value to assign
 * @return the modified stream
 */
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Wordnum& n) {
    string text;
    if (is >> text) {
        n.value_ = Wordnum::read_number(text);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Header File:

```
 #ifndef WORDNUM_H_
#define WORDNUM_H_

#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

/**
 * A class to read and write numbers in word form
 */

class Wordnum {
public:

    /**
     * Writes a number word string
     * 
     * @param n the number to write
     * @return the word string
     */
    static std::string write_number(int n);

    /**
     * Reads a number word string
     * 
     * @param n the string to read
     * @return the value read
     */
    static int read_number(std::string n);

    /**
     * Creates a new Wordnum for a given value
     * 
     * @param n the value of the number
     */
    Wordnum(int n = 0) {
        value_ = n;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Wordnum from a word string
     * 
     * @param n the value of the number
     */
    Wordnum(std::string n) {
        value_ = read_number(n);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Wordnum as a copy of another
     * 
     * @param n the value to copy
     */
    Wordnum(const Wordnum& n) {
        value_ = n.value_;
    }

    /**
     * Makes this equivalent to n
     * 
     * @param n the value to copy
     * @return the modified Wordnum
     */
    Wordnum& operator =(const Wordnum& n) {
        value_ = n.value_;
        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a Wordnum to an int
     * 
     * @return the value as an int
     */
    operator int () const {
        return value_;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a Wordnum to a string
     * 
     * @return the value as a word string
     */
    operator std::string() const {
        return write_number(value_);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a Wordnum into an output stream as a word string
     * 
     * @param os the stream to insert into
     * @param n the value to insert
     * @return the modified stream
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Wordnum& n);

    /**
     * Extracts a Wordnum in word string form from an input stream
     * 
     * @param is the stream to extract from
     * @param n the value to assign
     * @return the modified stream
     */
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &is, Wordnum& n);

    /**
     * Returns sum of n1 and n2
     */
    friend Wordnum operator +(const Wordnum& n1, const Wordnum& n2) {
        return Wordnum(n1.value_ + n2.value_);
    }

    /**
     * Returns difference of n1 and n2
     */
    friend Wordnum operator -(const Wordnum& n1, const Wordnum& n2) {
        return Wordnum(n1.value_ - n2.value_);
    }

    /**
     * Returns product of n1 and n2
     */
    friend Wordnum operator *(const Wordnum& n1, const Wordnum& n2) {
        return Wordnum(n1.value_ * n2.value_);
    }

    /**
     * Returns quotient of n1 and n2
     */
    friend Wordnum operator /(const Wordnum& n1, const Wordnum& n2) {
        return Wordnum(n1.value_ / n2.value_);
    }

private:
    int value_;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Have you run a debugger?

Comment: Where does the addition of the numbers happen?

Comment: Can we see the declaration of Wordnum?

Comment: By Overloading operators, they all must work fine, as they work for number without the word hundred in them.

Comment: @user1719605 Assumptions, assumptions. It's almost a given that bugs are caused by erroneous assumptions. I would post all the code. The error is probably somewhere else than you think.

Comment: You're right, I posted the header file. Assumptions could be what got me into this.

Comment: So you guys have any ideas on what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Converting from characters into ints isn't straight forward.
a char*(cstring) is an array of char, 
where each element is one byte(8 bits) in size

an integer is 4 bytes (32 bits), therefore, 
to properly convert from char to int you 
have to fill each of the 4 bytes with a char.
In other words, you need 4 chars to make an int.

as if that wasn't enough, there is another factor
that needs to be taken into account. The **endianness**
(i'll leave it up to you to look that up) of your 
system needs to be accounted for.

Endianness decides how your system stores data.
in a 16 bit integer for example say your storing the number 2
your system could store it in one of two ways:

way 1: 00000010 00000000

way 2: 00000000 00000010

since the 16 bit integer is stored in 2 bytes it can
either be right to left or left to right. [Here](http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/Java/archives/0902/krishnan/fig2.jpg)
is a picture.

Here is the code necessary to do an endian check and 
convert from char* (cstring) to int (32 bit integer)

```
bool isBigEndian(){
    int a = 1;
    return !((char*)&a)[0];
}

int convertToInt(char *charArr, int len){          //len should be <= 4
    int a = 0;
    if(!isBigEndian())
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            ((char*)&a)[i] = charArr[i];
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            ((char*)&a)[3-i] = charArr[i];
    return a;
}
```

as is the code will work for char* arrays of size 4 or less, anything more won't work
because ints can't hold more then 4 bytes. I recommend look up big endian vs little endian
before you look at the code and it'll make more sense. If you get an intuition of how this is done you could convert to types other then regular int, you could convert to Uint16(16 bit) or Uint8(8 bit; perfect size to store one char at a time in ;)

I hope you've solved this by now, if not, hope this helps.